# Change color of chess field after rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, subview

I newbie in `Obj-C`.
I have the following chess field:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {

        CGRect square = {horizontalOffSet + (column * squareSize),
                         verticalOffSet + (row * squareSize),
                         squareSize, squareSize};
        UIView *rect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:square];
        rect.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

        horizontalOffSet = horizontalOffSet + squareSize;
        if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
            //verticalOffSet = verticalOffSet + squareSize;
            horizontalOffSet = 0;
            rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [anotherRect addSubview:rect];
        } else {
            //verticalOffSet = verticalOffSet + squareSize;
            horizontalOffSet = 0;
            rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [anotherRect addSubview:rect];
        }
    }
}
```

My task to change colours of the field when it **rotates**, for example, fill it with cyan and purple colour when rotating on left. Not clearly understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@somerk check my updated code:

1) I have give identifier(`tag`) to identified chess view and which has white and which has black color. you can do it without identifier but in case of multiple `subviews` identifier is better way to get.

```
 int horizontalOffSet = 2;
    int squareSize = 40;
    int verticalOffSet = 2;

    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {

            CGRect square = {horizontalOffSet + (column * squareSize),
                verticalOffSet + (row * squareSize),
                squareSize, squareSize};
            UIView *rect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:square];
            rect.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

            horizontalOffSet = horizontalOffSet + squareSize;
            if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
                //verticalOffSet = verticalOffSet + squareSize;
                horizontalOffSet = 0;
                rect.tag = 101;
                rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                [self.view addSubview:rect];
            } else {
                //verticalOffSet = verticalOffSet + squareSize;
                rect.tag = 102;
                horizontalOffSet = 0;
                rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                [self.view addSubview:rect];
            }
        }
```

2) I have performed color change event on `UIButton` click so you have to use that code after rotation event.

```
-(IBAction)changeColor:(UIButton *)btn{
    for(UIView *rectViews in self.view.subviews){
        UIColor *clrblck = [UIColor blackColor];
        if(rectViews.backgroundColor == clrblck && rectViews.tag == 102){
            rectViews.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
        }else if(rectViews.backgroundColor == clrblck && rectViews.tag == 101){
            rectViews.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        }else{
             // you will get other views here..
        }
    }
}
```

- I have get all subviews and check `backgroundColor` and `tag` and change its `backgroundColor`.

**Note: change view'name according your view's name in `loop` and where you add  `rect` as `subviews` in your `anotherRect`.**

Free to ask me if you have any question. Happy Coding :)

Comment: it works good! Thanks! I'm only starting to investigate IBActions. I'm making little changes in your code for white colour and now it changes on purple :) Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful, enjoy working in obj c. You can use IBAction when you have to implement any action property such as, button, segment,switch.. you can do it programmatically as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks and happy coding for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Find another possible solution to change colors:

```
-(void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

CGFloat rndmColor1 = (float)(arc4random() % 256) / 255;
CGFloat rndmColor2 = (float)(arc4random() % 256) / 255;


for(UIView *rect in self.chessField.subviews){
    if (rect.tag == 102) {
        rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:rndmColor1 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1];
    } else if (rect.tag == 101) {
        rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:rndmColor2 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1];
    }
}
```

}